# aes_decryption don't work in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, aes

I have one table in mysql database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `t` (
  `q` varchar(257) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I added two values to it - one is through mysql-console and other from phpmyadmin:

```
insert into t(q) values(aes_encrypt('from phpmyadmin', 123456));
insert into t(q) values(aes_encrypt('from mysql console', 123456));
```

And I tried to display it:

```
select aes_decrypt(q,123456) from t;
```

From mysql-console I got the following out put:

```
mysql> select aes_decrypt(q,123456) from t;
+-----------------------+
| aes_decrypt(q,123456) |
+-----------------------+
| from phpmyadmin       |
| from mysql console    |
+-----------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

From phpadmin I got the following output:
[image]

why phpmyadmin don't show correct output?

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version are you using?

Comment: @MadhuraJayaratne Version information: 3.3.2deb1ubuntu1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`aes_decrypt` function produces binary data. 
Try

```
select cast(aes_decrypt(q,123456) as char) from t LIMIT 0, 30;
```

on your phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Note that you don't encounter this problem on Adminer

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query

```
select aes_decrypt(unhex(q),123456) from t;
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. You need to answer to the question, more than providing another solution.