# Why am I getting an error with no further details when using AES_DECRYPT?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm attempting to insert data with the AES_DECRYPT function, but I just get an error, with no further details - just *error*.

[image]

Comment: Hovering over the "ERROR" doesn't do anything. Clicking on the Go button, just highlights the ERROR text, but again, no further details.

Comment: Is this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836519/aes-decryption-dont-work-in-phpmyadmin/16875875 - related?

Comment: @raina77ow, no, I don't think so.